# 'TypeError: parse is not a function' when using gql

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I started out with [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-graphql-api-with-node-js-and-react-forms-8b13f4b26361) tutorial to learn graphql and reactjs and modified it.
Now I'm getting this error when trying to call gql:
[graphql error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3evXm.png)

This is the class that performs the call:

```
import React from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'

class BookForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            author: '',
            src: '',
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        this.props.addBook({
            variables: {
                author: this.state.author,
                title: this.state.title,
                src: this.state.src
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="book__form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Title:
                    <input type="text" name="title" value={this.srtate.title} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <label>
                    Author:
                    <input type="text" name="author" value={this.state.author} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <label>
                Src:
                <input type="text" name="src" value={this.state.src} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </label>
            </form>
        );
    }
}


const addBook =  gql `mutation addBook ($author: String!, $title: String!, $: ID!) {
    addBook(author: $author, title: $title, src: $src) {
      id,
      author,
      title,
      src,
    }
  }`

const addBookWithMutation = graphql(addBook)(BookForm);
export default addBookWithMutation;
```

Query-ing graphql returns all the data but now when I'm trying to add new data I'm not getting anywhere.
Am I doing something wrong in my code or is this a problem with graphql-tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a compatibility issue where version 0.13.1 of graphql-js breaks graphql-tag.  You can fix by manually working around the versioning issues -

```
yarn add apollo-boost@0.1.1 graphql@0.13.0 react-apollo@2.0.4
```

For reference, here is the [issue on github](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag/issues/155)